# Why does Firefox support min-height: fit-content, but not height: fit-content?

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser

I was looking at caniuse.com's reference for height: fit-content, and I noticed something odd. All major browsers support **min-height: fit-content** and have for years, but Firefox does not support **height: fit-content** and has only partial support for **max-height: fit-content**. Is there a reason related to performance and the way the browsers implement the CSSOM? How come Firefox is alone in lacking support? Is there something wrong with **fit-content**? Also, is its usage a code-smell?

[image: Firefox does not support height: fit-content]

[image: Firefox supports height: fit-content]

Comment: According to MDN [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content Firefox implements it but still requires the vendor prefix. Perhaps try it and see if OK?